# (Solved) need php script to remove the slash from the end of the url

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Removing a forward-slash from the tail-end of an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030661/php-removing-a-forward-slash-from-the-tail-end-of-an-url)

Hi,

i have a url that looks like example.com/

i would need to remove the slash from the end and i was thinking at using the substract function. if this might work, please let me know how to do it.

if there's another way other than substract function, that would be good as well.

i'd appreciate your input on this.